# Calling a webpage from another webpage via jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to figure out how to do the following.

I have webpage at a certian location called `www.hello.com/logout.jsp`

What I am trying to do with `logout.jsp` is delete all the cookies that were stored when initially logging in. The problem is that there exists a cookie for a website with a different domain that is stored when logging in. The one way I can delete that cookie is through the logout link for that website e.g. `www.hello2.com/logout.jsp`

Is there anyway I can call `www.hello2.com/logout.jsp` from `www.hello.com/logout.jsp`?
I am trying to just make a call for `www.hello2.com/logout.jsp` from `www.hello.com/logout.jsp` and then redirect the user to another page on `www.hello.com`

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Any chance to use subdomains like `hello.domain.com` and `hello2.domain.com`? It would then be much easier to share cookies.

Comment: Couldnt, but i figured it out. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do an HTTP POST( or GET ) to www.hello2.com/logout.jsp while processing HTTP request to your web application's `logout.jsp`.

You should really consider coding your logic in Servlets and using JSPs only to present data, but in the meantime you can create a scriptlet inside your logout.jsp and do a call to another web page in there ( just don't code the whole thing in JSP, only make a call to a static method ).

In that static method you can use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to do whatever HTTP request you need from www.hello2.com.

Here are additions to your logout.jsp

```
<%@ page import="my.package.Hello2Call" %>

<%
    Hello2Call.postLogoutRequest( );
%>
```